# Get zip file entries in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, c#-2.0

I need to get the number of entries and original file size of each entry in a ZIP file. On .NET 4.5, we can use the C# classes ZipArchive and ZipFile as shown below, but these classes are not available in .NET 2.0. What are my options then?

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(fileName))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[INFO] Zip entry {0} original file size: [{1}]", entry.name, entry.Length);
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're own your own. What reasons are there even to use .NET 2.0 in this age?

Comment: There are some servers in my company still using .NET 2.0. For my previously written programs, I had to compile for .NET 2.0. I will have to find out whether this new program that I am developing with be hosted on a higher .NET version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [ICsharpZipLib] (https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/)

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

public void ExtractZipFile(string archiveFilenameIn, string password, string outFolder) {
    ZipFile zf = null;
    try {
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(archiveFilenameIn);
        zf = new ZipFile(fs);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
            zf.Password = password;     // AES encrypted entries are handled automatically
        }
        foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in zf) {
            if (!zipEntry.IsFile) {
                continue;           // Ignore directories
            }
            String entryFileName = zipEntry.Name;
            // to remove the folder from the entry:- entryFileName = Path.GetFileName(entryFileName);
            // Optionally match entrynames against a selection list here to skip as desired.
            // The unpacked length is available in the zipEntry.Size property.

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];     // 4K is optimum
            Stream zipStream = zf.GetInputStream(zipEntry);

            // Manipulate the output filename here as desired.
            String fullZipToPath = Path.Combine(outFolder, entryFileName);
            string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullZipToPath);
            if (directoryName.Length > 0)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

            // Unzip file in buffered chunks. This is just as fast as unpacking to a buffer the full size
            // of the file, but does not waste memory.
            // The "using" will close the stream even if an exception occurs.
            using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(fullZipToPath)) {
                StreamUtils.Copy(zipStream, streamWriter, buffer);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (zf != null) {
            zf.IsStreamOwner = true; // Makes close also shut the underlying stream
            zf.Close(); // Ensure we release resources
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose the third party library is a DLL file that I need to place some where?

Comment: Yeah you could place it in your project folder and add it as a reference in your project